# Is it possible to make a corner and/or edge appear flat?

Tags: edges, normals, shadows, smooth

So I am creating this model for a client and I am trying to keep it really low poly. There is a slight corner at the edge of a mesh that I want to hide (I want this piece of mesh that extends out to look smooth). However, since the mesh is bent at a slight angle, there is a visible edge that I want to hide. I don't want to create more topology and I already tried Shade Smooth and Auto Smooth.

Is there a way to adjust the normals of an edge to give the appearance of it being flat? If not, is there any other way of doing this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bevelling that edge could solve it, but as you said you don't want more topology, that's not what you want. I'm not sure if there's another way, since geometry is needed to curve anything.

Comment: "Custom split normals"

Comment: Can you upload a file so we can test on your topology?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a Data Transfer modifier. One of the functions of this modifier allows you to transfer Face Normals from one mesh to another.

Source Object:

[image: Source Object]

Target Object:

**[image: Target Object]**

Modifier Setup:

[image: Modifier Setup]

Result:

[image: Result]

You could basically model a higher or lower poly version of your model that looks how you want the low poly mesh to look, and then transfer the normals. It can only work with the topology you have in the source mesh, so it has it's limits obviously, and you may have to play with the position and topology of the HP, But I think this is the closest option you're looking for.